# Increment cell by 1 per new row added with specific data

Tags: excel

I have a data table which is a list of items, and each item can be chosen from a drop-down menu.
I want to have a cell that will increment by one for each item that is being added to the list with a specific value.

In somewhat of a coding way:

```
U2 = FOREACH(Cell in Column C that equals "X") => increment by one;
U3 = FOREACH(Cell in Column C that equals "Y") => increment by one;
```

Where X and Y can be chosen from a drop-down menu I've created for column C.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly: `C2 = COUNTIF($C$1:C2,C2)+1`

This will give you the count of items thus far in the list with the value of C2 plus 1 (I think that's what you mean incremented by 1?).

If I misunderstood and you just want to know that each row is the nth time the item appears in the list then: `C2 = COUNTIF($C$1:C2,C2)`

Comment: The second one is exactly what I needed, just with U2 instead of C2 as I want the result to appear in a different cell. But indeed perhaps a clearer request of my side would have been "count the amount of items of specific type in column".
Thank you!